# javascript setInterval paused when screen is locked (IOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, reactjs, browser

This issue occurs on **IOS** device only. When the screen of **iphone** is locked the setInterval stop executing.

eg:
If `10 sec` is set in `setInterval()` for **every** `1 sec` the number will reduce to `9,8,7....,0`, but when I **locked** the screen at `8sec` for `2sec` the timer should be continuing to `7,6...0`, instead what happened was, when I open the screen again the timer starts from `8sec` again instead of `6sec`.

Working fine in ANDROID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take different approach. save initial time and reduce value from current time.

```js
let start = new Date().getTime();
    setInterval(x=>{
      console.log( parseInt( (new Date().getTime()-start)/1000))
    }, 1000)
```