# javascript setInterval stops on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I have simple webpage in javascript, that automatically run specific function after 15 seconds. Unfortunately I noticed that in mobile browser, clock stops when screen is locked.

```
timer = setInterval(function() { 
   FunctionABC(); 
   }, 15000)
```

I was looking through relevant discussions, but didn't find anything that suits me. Can you please advice?

Comment: [Many, many relevant discussions](https://www.google.com/search?q=setInterval+locked+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: I found this discussion, but can't apply it for my needs - not that good in JS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275004/javascript-setinterval-paused-when-screen-is-locked-ios

Comment: So what do you expect from us?

Comment: What is the effect you are looking for? That FunctionABC will be run when the phone is unlocked and 15 seconds have passed, or that it is run 15 seconds after unlocking or what? It will NOT run while locked

Comment: My scenario is that user open webpage, clock starts and should run Function ABC after 15 sec whenever user has open browser or locks mobile phone.

Comment: And as we have concluded, that is not possible. The interval will stop when a clmputer sleeps or a phone is locked. So you will have to handle your function when the page is active and handle that you are NOT called when the device is not active